# Using multiple processors in a Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container

I have a *docker container* on the centos 7 server. This container needs the most processor power to run calculations faster. The host server has **four processors** as shown in the image below.

[image]

But when we see the statistics of the host server (While the code Is running ), the **Docker container uses only 25% of the host server's resources**.
[image]

And when we look at the status of the container's processor from the docker stats command, all **100%** of it is in use .
[image]

**I made some changes in --cpuscpus container to use three processors 0, 1 and 2 but no change.**
Where is the problem?

[image]

Comment: If not explicitly limited a Docker container can use all of CPUs, but the application hast to support using multiple CPUs as well.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you but How Can I Know the Host support multiple CPUs?

Comment: Your application needs to be written to use threads or some other concurrency mechanism, the same way it would without Docker.  There's nothing particularly special about Docker here other than it being a little bit easier to limit the total CPU utilization.

Comment: It might be helpful to [edit] your question to include the actual application source code and any other details required for a [mcve].  Make sure to include these details as text and not images; you should almost never paste a screen shot of a terminal window into a question, include the actual text instead.